# Android error cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: android, string, button

in my application I have a numeric keypad, formed by 9 buttons. Through a class I get the numbers selected for the strings.
I get the error when I try to get them.

in onCreate

```
int numberButtons[] = {R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3,
            R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7,
            R.id.b8, R.id.b9, R.id.b0};
    NumberButtonClickListener numberClickListener = new NumberButtonClickListener();
    for (int id : numberButtons) {
        View v = findViewById(id);
        v.setOnClickListener(numberClickListener);
    }
```

the class:

```
private class NumberButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = (String) ((Button) v).getText();
        setCurrentString(getCurrentString() + text);
    }

    public void setCurrentString(String s) {
        currentString = s;
        new_psw.setText(s);
    }

    public String getCurrentString() {
        return currentString;
    }
}
```

the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

at this line:

```
String text = (String) ((Button) v).getText();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: 
`String text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();`

Answer (score 2):

it looks like your `Button` doesn't contain simple text, but a `SpannableString` object. You can either cast the return value to `CharSequence` which both `String` and `Spannable` implement without loosing the Spannable markups, or use `toString()` to retrive the current content. You can also call `Button.append(getCurrentString())` you want to append some additional text.